# Shock model conditional expectation

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Consider a shock model where $A(t) = \sum _{i=1}^{N(t)}A_i e^{-(\alpha-S_i)}$ where $N(t)$ is distributed as a Poisson, $A_i$ is the amplitude of the shock, distributed as $U(0,5)$, and $S{_i}$ is the arrival time of the $i$th shock according to $N(t)$.

I need to find the expected value by conditioning on $N(T)$, where I know that  $ E\left( \sum _{i=1}^{N(t)} x_i\right) = E(N(t))E(X_i)$ based on the double expectation $E[E(\sum _{i=1}^{N(t)} X_i\mid N(t))] $, but I'm getting thrown by the Uniform distribution $A_i$. I hope someone can help me find the expected value of this, please.

Comment: I'm guessing the MathJax code here was done by one of those softwares that do that somehow (I forgot what they're called; I don't have any hint of how to find them) since it looked like something written by a psychotic.  One thing I've never seen before this present posting is several occurrences here of S{_i} and A{_i}, etc., instead of S_i and A_i.  I've cleaned it up. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: For some reason I was never able to get a LaTex software to work on my PC so I go online sometimes when I can't remember syntax. Believe me I'm trying to work on it and I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem probably wants you to assume that the size of the $i$th shock is independent of the process $N$ (and hence $S$). In that case $E[A_i e^{-(\alpha-S_i)}] = E[A_i] E[e^{-(\alpha-S_i)}] = \frac{5}{2} E[e^{-(\alpha-S_i)}]$.

Here we used that if $A\sim U[a,b]$ then $E[A] = \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b x\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\frac{b^2-a^2}{b-a} = \frac{a+b}{2}$.